# log4j2 how to to log a package?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I need support to log a specific package into chats.log and errors into error.log. How to do this correct? 
So far I created threshold filters in several appenders, but error.log stays empty and chats.log has one entry, which does not belong to the specific package. After all I read carefully, also tried 2 days solving this, the documentation of log4j and followed several tutorials on web sites and youtube.
I tried also this: [Apache Log4j2 package specific logging using log4j2.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38713575/apache-log4j2-package-specific-logging-using-log4j2-xml)
I tried also old log4j tutorial, but this ended in errors.

Theses are the files I use inside the maven project structure.
src/main/resources/log4j2.properties

```
status = error
name = PropertiesConfig

######################################
# Global properties as varies
######################################
property.logPath = logs

######################################
# Filters and properties of filters
######################################
filters = threshold

filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = all

######################################
# Appenders Section for roles
######################################
appenders = rolling, console, rolling2, errorAppender, service

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.immediateFlush= true
appender.rolling.append = true
appender.rolling.fileName = ${logPath}/server.log
appender.rolling.filePattern = debug-backup-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 20
appender.rolling.filter.threshold.type = LevelRangeFilter
appender.rolling.filter.threshold.minLevel = INFO
appender.rolling.filter.threshold.maxLevel = INFO
appender.rolling.filter.threshold.onMatch = ACCEPT
appender.rolling.filter.threshold.onMismatch = DENY

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

appender.rolling2.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling2.name = debugLog
appender.rolling2.immediateFlush= true
appender.rolling2.append = true
appender.rolling2.fileName = ${logPath}/debug.log
appender.rolling2.filePattern = debug-backup-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling2.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling2.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.rolling2.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling2.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling2.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling2.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling2.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling2.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.rolling2.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling2.strategy.max = 20
appender.rolling2.filter.threshold.type = LevelRangeFilter
appender.rolling2.filter.threshold.minLevel = DEBUG
appender.rolling2.filter.threshold.maxLevel = DEBUG
appender.rolling2.filter.threshold.onMatch = ACCEPT
appender.rolling2.filter.threshold.onMismatch = DENY

appender.errorAppender.type = RollingFile
appender.errorAppender.name = errorLog
appender.errorAppender.immediateFlush= true
appender.errorAppender.append = true
appender.errorAppender.fileName = ${logPath}/error.log
appender.errorAppender.filePattern = debug-backup-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.errorAppender.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.errorAppender.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.errorAppender.policies.type = Policies
appender.errorAppender.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.errorAppender.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.errorAppender.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.errorAppender.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.errorAppender.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.errorAppender.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.errorAppender.strategy.max = 20
appender.errorAppender.filter.threshold.type = LevelRangeFilter
appender.errorAppender.filter.threshold.minLevel = ERROR
appender.errorAppender.filter.threshold.maxLevel = ERROR
appender.errorAppender.filter.threshold.onMatch = ACCEPT
appender.errorAppender.filter.threshold.onMismatch = DENY

appender.service.type = RollingFile
appender.service.name = chats
appender.service.append = true
appender.service.fileName = ${logPath}/chats.log
appender.service.filePattern = chats-backup-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.service.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.service.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.service.policies.type = Policies
appender.service.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.service.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.service.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.service.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.service.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.service.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.service.strategy.max = 20
appender.service.filter.threshold.type = LevelRangeFilter
appender.service.filter.threshold.minLevel = INFO
appender.service.filter.threshold.maxLevel = INFO
appender.service.filter.threshold.onMatch = ACCEPT
appender.service.filter.threshold.onMismatch = DENY

######################################
# Loggers Section for file write
######################################
loggers = rolling, package

logger.rolling.name = org.remad.logging
logger.rolling.appenderRefs = rolling, debugLog, errorLog
logger.rolling.level = all
logger.rolling.additivity = true
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling2.ref = debugLog

logger.package.name = org.remad.logging.protocol.Protocol
logger.package.appenderRefs = service
logger.package.level = info
logger.package.additivity = false
logger.package.appenderRef.service.ref = chats

######################################
# RootLogger Section for settings
######################################
rootLogger.level = all
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout, chats, errorLog
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
rootLogger.appenderRef.service.ref = chats
rootLogger.apenderRef.errorAppender.ref = errorLog
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.remad</groupId>
    <artifactId>Logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <!-- Global project properties                                              -->
    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <!-- project Dependencies                                                   -->
    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <!-- project build with plugins                                             -->
    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>10</source>
                    <target>10</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>org.remad.logging.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

src/main/org.remad.logging.Main.java

```
package org.remad.logging;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.remad.logging.protocol.Protocol;

public class Main {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String message = "Hello there!";
        LoggerEntryPoint loggerEntryPoint = new LoggerEntryPoint();
        Protocol protocol = new Protocol();
        logger.trace(message);
        logger.debug(message);
        logger.info(message);
        logger.warn(message);
        logger.error(message);
        logger.fatal(message);
        loggerEntryPoint.entries();
        protocol.logSomeMessages();
    }
}
```

org.remad.logging.LoggerEntryPoint.java

```
package org.remad.logging;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class LoggerEntryPoint {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(LoggerEntryPoint.class);

    public LoggerEntryPoint() {}

    public void entries() {
        logger.info("now in " + getClass().getCanonicalName());
        logger.error("now error.");
        logger.debug("hggxdfghcdft");
    }
}
```

org.remad.logging.protocol.Protocol.java

```
package org.remad.logging.protocol;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class Protocol {

    public Protocol() {}

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Protocol.class);

    public void logSomeMessages() {
        logger.fatal("Fatal error.");
        logger.error("Error happened.");
        logger.warn("Warning message.");
        logger.info("This message informs.");
        logger.debug("Debug message.");
        logger.info("This is also chat message");
    }
}
```

logs/server.log

```
2020-05-18 17:24:42 INFO  Main:17 - Hello there!
2020-05-18 17:24:42 INFO  LoggerEntryPoint:13 - now in org.remad.logging.LoggerEntryPoint
```

logs/error.log

logs/debug.log

```
2020-05-18 17:24:42 DEBUG Main:16 - Hello there!
2020-05-18 17:24:42 DEBUG LoggerEntryPoint:15 - hggxdfghcdft
```

logs/chats.log

```
2020-05-18 17:24:42 INFO  Main:17 - Hello there!
2020-05-18 17:24:42 INFO  LoggerEntryPoint:13 - now in org.remad.logging.LoggerEntryPoint
2020-05-18 17:24:42 INFO  Protocol:16 - This message informs.
2020-05-18 17:24:42 INFO  Protocol:18 - This is also chat message
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a global threshold filter with a level set to ALL. This means that every log event is going to be sent to an appender, regardless of the logging levels set on the loggers. You also have the Root logging level set to ALL. This is a very bad practice as it will lead to performance issues as every logging call will create a LogEvent and because you are capturing line numbers every event will need to capture the location information by walking the thread's stacktrace.

Get rid of the Global threshold filter. You don't need it for your case.  Set the Root logging level to DEBUG and then set the logging level of the appender references to match what you want to log.

I have modified your configuration to what I believe will work, but I have not tried it. I prefer the XML syntax so don't be surprised if I made a typo.

```
status = error
name = PropertiesConfig

######################################
# Global properties as varies
######################################
property.logPath = logs


######################################
# Appenders Section for roles
######################################
appenders = rolling, console, rolling2, errorAppender, service

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.immediateFlush= true
appender.rolling.append = true
appender.rolling.fileName = ${logPath}/server.log
appender.rolling.filePattern = debug-backup-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 20
appender.rolling.filter.threshold.type = LevelRangeFilter
appender.rolling.filter.threshold.minLevel = INFO
appender.rolling.filter.threshold.maxLevel = INFO
appender.rolling.filter.threshold.onMatch = ACCEPT
appender.rolling.filter.threshold.onMismatch = DENY

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

appender.rolling2.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling2.name = debugLog
appender.rolling2.immediateFlush= true
appender.rolling2.append = true
appender.rolling2.fileName = ${logPath}/debug.log
appender.rolling2.filePattern = debug-backup-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling2.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling2.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.rolling2.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling2.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling2.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling2.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling2.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling2.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.rolling2.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling2.strategy.max = 20
appender.rolling2.filter.threshold.type = LevelRangeFilter
appender.rolling2.filter.threshold.minLevel = DEBUG
appender.rolling2.filter.threshold.maxLevel = DEBUG
appender.rolling2.filter.threshold.onMatch = ACCEPT
appender.rolling2.filter.threshold.onMismatch = DENY

appender.errorAppender.type = RollingFile
appender.errorAppender.name = errorLog
appender.errorAppender.immediateFlush= true
appender.errorAppender.append = true
appender.errorAppender.fileName = ${logPath}/error.log
appender.errorAppender.filePattern = debug-backup-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.errorAppender.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.errorAppender.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.errorAppender.policies.type = Policies
appender.errorAppender.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.errorAppender.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.errorAppender.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.errorAppender.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.errorAppender.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.errorAppender.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.errorAppender.strategy.max = 20
appender.errorAppender.filter.threshold.type = LevelRangeFilter
appender.errorAppender.filter.threshold.minLevel = ERROR
appender.errorAppender.filter.threshold.maxLevel = ERROR
appender.errorAppender.filter.threshold.onMatch = ACCEPT
appender.errorAppender.filter.threshold.onMismatch = DENY

appender.service.type = RollingFile
appender.service.name = chats
appender.service.append = true
appender.service.fileName = ${logPath}/chats.log
appender.service.filePattern = chats-backup-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.service.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.service.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.service.policies.type = Policies
appender.service.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.service.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.service.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.service.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.service.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.service.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.service.strategy.max = 20
appender.service.filter.threshold.type = LevelRangeFilter
appender.service.filter.threshold.minLevel = INFO
appender.service.filter.threshold.maxLevel = INFO
appender.service.filter.threshold.onMatch = ACCEPT
appender.service.filter.threshold.onMismatch = DENY

######################################
# Loggers Section for file write
######################################
loggers = rolling, package

logger.rolling.name = org.remad.logging
logger.rolling.appenderRefs = rolling, rolling2
logger.rolling.level = DEBUG
logger.rolling.additivity = true
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.level = INFO
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling2.ref = debugLog
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling2.ref = DEBUG

logger.package.name = org.remad.logging.protocol.Protocol
logger.package.appenderRefs = service
logger.package.level = info
logger.package.additivity = false
logger.package.appenderRef.service.ref = chats
logger.package.appenderRef.service.level = INFO

######################################
# RootLogger Section for settings
######################################
rootLogger.level = INFO
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout, chats, errorLog
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.level = INFO
rootLogger.appenderRef.service.ref = chats
rootLogger.appenderRef.service.level = INFO
rootLogger.apenderRef.errorAppender.ref = errorLog
rootLogger.appenderRef.errorAppender.ref = ERROR
```

I left the filters on the Appenders to filter ONLY the level you wanted. I am not sure why you would only want INFO or ERROR messages on a particular Appender instead if the default of that level and more specific but I left it. If you really don't need that then remove those filters.

Comment: Hello rgoers, I thank you for explaining me. I am new and I read the documentation of the log4j2, however, not everything is clear as beginner. I leave later a feedback, if this has worked.

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
status = error
name = PropertiesConfig

######################################
# Global properties as varies
######################################
property.logPath = logs

######################################
# Appenders Section for log-files
######################################
appenders = rolling, console, rolling2, errorAppender, service

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.immediateFlush= true
appender.rolling.append = true
appender.rolling.fileName = ${logPath}/server.log
appender.rolling.filePattern = server-log-backup-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max = 20
appender.rolling.filter.threshold.type = LevelRangeFilter
appender.rolling.filter.threshold.minLevel = info
appender.rolling.filter.threshold.maxLevel = info
appender.rolling.filter.threshold.onMatch = ACCEPT
appender.rolling.filter.threshold.onMismatch = DENY

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

appender.rolling2.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling2.name = debugLog
appender.rolling2.immediateFlush= true
appender.rolling2.append = true
appender.rolling2.fileName = ${logPath}/debug.log
appender.rolling2.filePattern = debug-backup-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.rolling2.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling2.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.rolling2.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling2.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling2.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling2.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling2.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling2.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.rolling2.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling2.strategy.max = 20
appender.rolling2.filter.threshold.type = LevelRangeFilter
appender.rolling2.filter.threshold.minLevel = DEBUG
appender.rolling2.filter.threshold.maxLevel = DEBUG
appender.rolling2.filter.threshold.onMatch = ACCEPT
appender.rolling2.filter.threshold.onMismatch = DENY

appender.errorAppender.type = RollingFile
appender.errorAppender.name = errorLog
appender.errorAppender.immediateFlush= true
appender.errorAppender.append = true
appender.errorAppender.fileName = ${logPath}/error.log
appender.errorAppender.filePattern = error-log-backup-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.errorAppender.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.errorAppender.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.errorAppender.policies.type = Policies
appender.errorAppender.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.errorAppender.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.errorAppender.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.errorAppender.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.errorAppender.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.errorAppender.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.errorAppender.strategy.max = 20
appender.errorAppender.filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
appender.errorAppender.filter.threshold.level = warn

appender.service.type = RollingFile
appender.service.name = chats
appender.service.append = true
appender.service.fileName = ${logPath}/chats.log
appender.service.filePattern = chats-log-backup-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz
appender.service.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.service.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.service.policies.type = Policies
appender.service.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.service.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.service.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.service.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.service.policies.size.size=10MB
appender.service.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.service.strategy.max = 20
appender.service.filter.threshold.type = LevelRangeFilter
appender.service.filter.threshold.minLevel = INFO
appender.service.filter.threshold.maxLevel = INFO
appender.service.filter.threshold.onMatch = ACCEPT
appender.service.filter.threshold.onMismatch = DENY

######################################
# Loggers for logging different packages
######################################
loggers = package

# RootLogger write all into logs, besides chats.log
rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.additivity = false
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout, rolling, rolling2, errorLog
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling2.ref = debugLog
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling2.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRef.errorAppender.ref = errorLog
rootLogger.appenderRef.errorAppender.level = warn

# Logs only chat messages of class: org.remad.logging.protocol.Protocol
logger.package.name = org.remad.logging.protocol.Protocol
logger.package.additivity = false
logger.package.level = info
logger.package.appenderRefs = service
logger.package.appenderRef.service.ref = chats
logger.package.appenderRef.service.level = info
```